# bash pattern substitution to remove an arbitrary long sequence of letters

Tags: bash

My script deals about filenames which are padded by the letter x to a certain length, so a file may be abcdxxxxxx or fooxxxxxxx. I have the filename stored in a variable `fn`, and I want to extract just the "stem", i.e. *abcd* or *foo*.

I obviously can do this by forking a `sed` or `tr` process and feed the file name into it, but bash also has a feature called *pattern substitution* for variables, and I was wondering whether this could be used.

From the bash man page:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>                 Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string.  If  pattern  begins  with  /,  **all** matches of pattern are replaced with string.  Normally only the first match is replaced....  If pattern begins with %, it must match at  the  **end** of  the expanded value of parameter.

Now, a pattern denoting the letter x is just `x`, and since the pattern should match at the end, I need `%x`

```
echo ${fn/%x/}
```

indeed return the filename with the last x removed. But I want to have all x removed, i.e. all occurences of the pattern, which requires according to the man-page that the pattern starts with a slash. I understand this to turn `%x` into either `/%x` or `%/x` However, neither `echo ${fn//%x/}` nor `echo ${fn/%/x/}` produce the expected result.

Did I misunderstand something in the description of pattern substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the substring replacements (`/`, `//`, `/%`, `/#`). Towards the end in here [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

**${var/Pattern/Replacement}**

First match of *Pattern*, within *var* replaced with *Replacement*.

**${var//Pattern/Replacement}**

Global replacement. All matches of *Pattern*, within *var* replaced with *Replacement*.

**${var/#Pattern/Replacement}**

If *prefix* of *var* matches *Pattern*, then substitute *Replacement* for *Pattern*.

**${var/%Pattern/Replacement}**

If *suffix* of *var* matches *Pattern*, then substitute *Replacement* for *Pattern*.

So, it's first match, all matches, prefix string or suffix string and as with [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) you can't `x*` in the sense of regular expressions, you are left with options described in the other answers.

Comment: I see. So this feature is not suitable for substitutions of "all occurances at the end". Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo "${fn%${fn##*[^x]}}"
```

#### Examples

```
$ fn=abcdxxxxxx; echo "${fn%${fn##*[^x]}}"
abcd
$ fn=fooxxxxxxx; echo "${fn%${fn##*[^x]}}"
foo
```

#### How it works

For starters, `${parameter##word}` is *prefix removal*.  It removes `word` from the beginning of `parameter`.  In our cvase, `${fn##*[^x]}` is the file with everything removed from the front up to an including the last character that is not `x`.  This leaves only the trailing x's.  For example:

```
$ fn=abcdxxxxxx; echo "${fn##*[^x]}"
xxxxxx
```

`${parameter%%word}` is *suffix removal*.  It removes `word` from the end of `$parameter`.  In our case, we want to removes trailing x's (as found above) from `$fn`.  Thus we want `${fn%${fn##*[^x]}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Doubling the percent sign will do what you want:

```
echo "${fn%%x*}"
```

"Remove, from the end of the string, x and all the characters that follow it"

Or you can use extended globs:

```bash
shopt -s extglob
echo "${fn/%+(x)/}"
```

"Replace, at the end of the string, a sequence of one or more x's with nothing"

Comment: This approach is nice and simple.  The reason I didn't use it is because it doesn't just remove trailing x's (which is what I, rightly or wrongly, interpreted as what the OP wanted); it removes from the _first_ `x` to the end of file name.  Consider `fn=xfooxxx`.

Comment: @John1024: But the extglob version works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the filename in the environment variable `fn`, then in bash you can do:

```sh
if [[ $fn =~ x+$ ]]; then
  echo ${fn%$BASH_REMATCH}
fi
```

This will print the filename with the matched part removed. If you want it to work also when there are no `x`:es at the end of the filename, replace `x+$` with `x*$` above, in which case it will always match.

As for the pattern substitution, my **guess** is it will only attempt the replace matches in the string once at a given location even if you add the `/` to replace all matches. So when it matches the last x at the end of the string, it will not go back to an earlier location in the string to see if it matches again. Basically this means you cannot combine `%` and `/`. If my guess is correct, that is :)